# How to do "file" field required in contact form 7 in WordPress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I want to display * sign in form and display error message under file field if no file selected.

My code:
[file* Send-file limit:2000000 filetypes:JPG|JPEG|PNG id:Send-file]

I want to display the text "Fältet är obligatoriskt" in the arrow sign when no file selected.

See image:

[image]

But it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can define validations for upload file like

Refer : https://wpdebuglog.com/forums/topic/contact-form-7-file-upload/

or if you want to modify you can give custom validations as i have used jquery validation template with contact form 7

https://jqueryvalidation.org/